# Windows networking protocols when file sharing

Tags: windows, performance, networking

I am curious to know which networking protocols are involved when Mapping a network share as a network drive from

- The same system
- A system on LAN

on Windows.

Basically, I am working on an MFC based application which interacts with files stored at a particular path.

I am getting a significant performance difference when I point it to a local physical drive vs when I point it to a local share mapped as a network drive vs when I point it to a network share mapped as a network drive.

Does the Network share always use TCP, even if the share is from the same system?

I have tried using Process Monitor to track and it looks like the network share has to do some kind of a resolution call before performing the actual operation

For example, the call to read from a file on the C Drive looks like:

```
Operation                       path                                        time        result

CreateFile                      C:\MyDir\database.ini                       0.0000316   SUCCESS
LockFile                        C:\MyDir\database.ini                       0.0000067   SUCCESS
QueryStandardInformationFile    C:\MyDir\database.ini                       0.0000071   SUCCESS
ReadFile                        C:\MyDir\database.ini                       0.0000388   SUCCESS
UnlockFileSingle                C:\MyDir\database.ini                       0.0000067   SUCCESS
CloseFile                       C:\MyDir\database.ini                       0.0000076   SUCCESS
```

While the same call, on a network drive looks like (D:\ mapped as \\NetworkShare)

```
Operation                       path                                        time        result

CreateFile                      \\NetworkShare\MyDir\database.ini           0.0470342   SUCCESS
LockFile                        \\NetworkShare\MyDir\database.ini           0.0000424   SUCCESS
LockFile                        D:\MyDir\database.ini                       0.0000089   SUCCESS
QueryStandardInformationFile    \\NetworkShare\MyDir\database.ini           0.0001107   SUCCESS
ReadFile                        \\NetworkShare\MyDir\database.ini           0.0000575   SUCCESS
ReadFile                        D:\MyDir\database.ini                       0.0000259   SUCCESS
UnlockFileSingle                \\NetworkShare\MyDir\database.ini           0.0000504   SUCCESS
UnlockFileSingle                D:\MyDir\database.ini                       0.0000089   SUCCESS
CloseFile                       \\NetworkShare\MyDir\database.ini           0.0000973   SUCCESS
```

Is there anything which I can do to improve the overall speed when working on a network share?

Comment: You can get a faster network, and / or move the nodes onto the same network - other than that, that's just how networks work.

Comment: You can assume that TCP/IP via the loopback interface is faster than TCP via an NIC, and you can also make a good guess that access to a local share isn't going to involve the network at all.

Comment: I believe the difference is when you map a drive, a drive letter is assigned and you can refer to the location using D: . If you add a network location, you are merely "bookmarking" that UNC location in your my computer. A mapped network drive (if possible) would give you more "freedom" and functionality compared to a network location.

Comment: I don't know whether the network share uses TCP on the local system; it may well do.  It definitely has to go through the workstation and server layers, which will add some overhead.